# How to get return result of JavaScript function in method of class in c#(mvc)?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc

Below is JavaScript function, which I have to call in my method of class in C#. 
Function is used to decrypt the jwt token and return result.

```
JWS.verify = function(o, s, j) {
  //here return value can be Boolean, string, thrown error
};
```

Now, below is method of class in C#(MVC)

```
 public string Secure(string token)
    {
        //Here I want to call JavaScript function and get return result of java script
    }
```

How can I implement this ?
Thank you in advance :)

Comment: You want a method on server (C#) to call method on client (JS)? And have the answer on the server?

Comment: Call JS function from Method(Secure) and JS function(JWS.verify) return value should be get at Method(Secure).

Answer (score 0):

C# can't call JavaScript. JavaScript is a scripting language. It needs to be parsed by a runtime, which is usually contained in a browser. With the exception of using something like Node.js to set up a headless server, JavaScript is run *client-side*, whereas all your C# is run server-side.

If the situation is such that you can *only* use JavaScript to decrypt the token, then you'll either have to use Node, and then something like `WebClient` in C# to hit an endpoint on your Node server, or you'll have to post the value back from a webpage of some sort.

Comment: Have you missed to notice the "tags" on the question? I think he is referring to ASP.NET where you do C# as well as javascript.

Comment: Hello Chris Pratt,
Can you please give me example or any reference for what you describe in 2nd para (you'll either have to use Node, and then something like WebClient in C# to hit an endpoint on your Node server, or you'll have to post the value back from a webpage of some sort).

Comment: Simplistically, Node.js is just a CLI app that runs JavaScript. If you've used something like Ruby or Python in the past, it's very similar to their CLIs. However, it also extends JS somewhat to allow system integration. Therefore you can do something like actually set up a headless server that can run JavaScript server-side and remotely. In C# you just need to communicate with this somehow. You could use WebClient to do a remote HTTP request, or you could probably even run the Node.js CLI directly and take the console output.

Comment: The main point is that C# can't do anything with JS on its own. It must either send a request to something that can run JS (Node), run a system application that can process JS (Node) or receive a request from AJAX or a standard HTML form (where the JS was run client-side in the browser).

Answer (score 0):

## ASP.NET Solution

Register your javascript function on your server code, call it when needed and have a hidden field in your web page to store the return value. Get the hidden field value from your server code.

**C#:**

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, typeof(string), "callJavascript", "callJavascript();", true);
    }    
}

protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "callJavascript", "callJavascript();", true);
    String token=HiddenField1.Value;
    Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "showReturn", "showReturn('" + token + "');", true);
}
```

**Webpage (javascript):**

```
<script language="javascript">
    /*This function gets called from Codebehind*/
    function callJavascript() {
        document.getElementById('<%= HiddenField1.ClientID %>').value = "Token Return value";
    }

    /* This function is just to show/test the return value*/
    function showReturn(token) {
        alert(token);
    }
</script>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>

        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" onclick="Button1_Click" 
            Text="Call Javascript" />
        <asp:HiddenField ID="HiddenField1" runat="server" />
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
```

## Update #1: ASP.NET MVC Solution

The above one was just ASP.NET example. I am leaving it as is and updating the answer with MVC ASP.NET example. The below example uses ajax.post to controller to trigger a function call and do communication.

**HomeController:**

```
   [HandleError]
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult SecureCall(String param)
        {
            return Json("token123456");
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult DecryptResult(String param)
        {
            return Json("OK Got the decrypted token:" + param);
        }

        public ActionResult About()
        {
            ViewBag.Message = "Your application description page.";

            return View();
        }

        public ActionResult Contact()
        {
            ViewBag.Message = "Your contact page.";

            return View();
        }
    }
```

**Index page (Javascript):**

```
<script language="javascript">
    function TriggerAction()
    {
        callAjax("SecureCall", "");
    }

    function DecryptToken(token) {
        return "54321nekot";
    }

    function ajaxCallResult(result, action)
    {
        if (action==="SecureCall")
        {
            var dtoken = DecryptToken(result);
            callAjax("DecryptResult", dtoken);
        }
        else if (action==="DecryptResult")
        {
            alert("Decrypt Result :"+result);
        }
        else if (action==="error")
        {
            alert("Error: "+action+" call failed!");
        }
    }

    function callAjax(action, param) {

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/Home/"+action,    
            data: {param: param},
            success: function (result) {
                ajaxCallResult(result, action);
            },
            error: function (req, status, error) {
                ajaxCallResult("error", action);
            }
        });
    }
</script>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
}

<p><a href="#" onclick="TriggerAction();" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Click here to trigger a Ajax call</a></p>
```

The above example will have a link in the index page which when you click, calls TriggerAction() script function which inturn calls callAjax() function with Controller Action details - This is to initiate a communication with the controller, to let controller know that you are expecting a token. SecureCall() in controller gets the post request from callAjax(), returns a token. ajaxCallResult() handles the result data you receive from controller which calls callAjax() function again with decrypted token value and DecryptResult() in your controller gets called.

Basically, you use Ajax http post option to communicate with your Controller code.

Comment: I need return value of JavaScript function and I am using Asp.net MVC framework.So please suggest how I will get JS function(JWS.verify) value in method(Secure) of class.

Comment: @Hrdk, Updated the answer with ASP.NET MVC excample. Please check "Update#1" if it solves the problem. There is no direct way you can do it, but using ajax.post, you can achieve what you want.